# Android studio shows only white screen when trying to open an insecure URL in WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, uri, mobile-website

**My Goal**

Open the website I have created.

**What problem I am facing**

When the application launch it only show white screen like this

[image]

**Information**

I tested my code, it works totally fine with normal secure website like https://www.google.com but not mine. Is there anyway to make the application at least show the page below[image] so that I can click advanced and proceed to my website? I created the application followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8sSRQ5mVqY). My code is identical to the one being shown in the video, I have just changed the link.

Answer (score 0):

try to setup [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config), you will probably need below line for allowing non-TLS URLs (e.g. common `http` without `s` on the end)

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
```

or more "global" way

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
```

or even simpler way would be to just add flag to manifest without any additional XML file

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    .... />
```